# When is \relax necessary after a \ifcase#1 statement

Tags: tex-core

In the LaTeX kernel (`latex.ltx`) we see some examples of
`\ifcase#1\or a\or b\or ...` (an `\ifcase` without an added `\relax`),
but when we look at some packages most of them add this statement
after the `\ifcase#1`. So my question is: when is this required?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer given by @wipet explains the need to separate the evaluation of the number after `\ifcase` from the material that is used if that result is zero and it explains why both "space" or `\relax` can be wrong depending on the input.

As far as LaTeX is concerned: when LaTeX was initially written every byte did count so we dropped any explicit separation whenever it wasn't necessary, e.g.,

```
  \ifcase#1\or
```

here the zero case is empty and the `\or` tells TeX that the number to evaluate has finished. In cases like

```
\ifcase\@eqcnt
```

we know that `\@eqcnt` is a counter so no space or `\relax` is needed (or even correct)

Finally, if you actually don't know what the input data is, then you have to resort to the solution, which @wipet found together with David Carlisle, i.e.,

```
\def\zaprelax#1\relax{#1 }

 \ifcase\expandafter\zaprelax\number#1\relax
```

(in `latex.ltx` there is one case of `\ifcase\number#1` but that doesn't solve the general situation either (as I initially thought); it only works there as the input as used is actually not fully general. In other words `\hexnumber@` is fully correctly defined in the kernel. It wouldn't work if the input is a plain `0`.)

anyway, just ending the evaluation with `\relax` is wrong if you don't know what the input is as @wipet explained: it correctly stops the evaluation but you don't know if the `\relax` is gone or becomes part of the zero case!

So if you do

```
\def\foo#1{\ifcase#1\relax 7\or 8\else9\fi}
```

the replacement text for `\foo` could be just a number (7, 8 or 9) or `\relax 7` and the latter would act quite differently from the other cases.

So in short, the use of `\relax` in packages may be just unnecessary but it could be plain wrong.

Comment: I thought I convinced myself last century that `\number` didn't catch everything. will have to look again:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle surprise, isn't it? but just add it to \def\test#1{\ifcase#1 77zero\or one\fi} and see the difference

Comment: yes but try `\test{0}` once you add \number, the space goes in `\number` so `\ifcase` sees `077`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ouch. But that means \hexnumber@ in the kernel probably has a bug too (at least  conceptually) as it will lose the 0 if given a literal 0.

Answer (score 15):

The `\ifcase` has the syntax

```
\ifcase number zero case\or one\or two\or ...\fi
```

The "number" have to be separated from "zero case". The natural separator is space, but there are formats of the "number" where the "number" is compact (for example from `\countdef` of `\chardef` and the additional space gets the part of "zero case". You can try:

```
\def\test#1{\ifcase#1 77zero\or one\fi}  % note the space before "77zero"

literal:\test{0}  % the space is a separator of the number, it disappears

\newcount\tmpnum  \tmpnum=0
countdef:\test{\tmpnum}  % the space is a part of the zero case, it is printed 

\chardef\tmp=0
chardef:\test{\tmp}  % the space is a part of the zero case, it is printed

\end
```

If you need to have no space in zero case for every types of the number you can use `\relax` as the separator of the number. This prints nothing. But there is another problem: the \relax stays as a part of the result if the macro is used for expansion purposes only and zero case is evaluated.

**Edit:** How to solve the problem of various number format in `#1` in order to no space no `\relax` is expanded? IMHO it is possible only by eTeX primitive `\numexpr`:

```
\def\test#1{\ifcase\numexpr#1\relax 77zero\or 2one\fi}
```

**Edit2:** Thanks to Frank and David we have found (in the discussion below) the robust solution of the number separator in the classic TeX too:

```
\def\zaprelax#1\relax{#1 }
\def\test#1{\ifcase\expandafter\zaprelax\number#1\relax 77zero\or 2one\or two\fi}
```

Comment: +1 for numexpr, yes I think you are right that there is no way to make a "safe" termination in classic tex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought so first too, but the "absolutely unnecessary" \number primitive is your friend here (see my answer). So there is a way in TeX too.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I can't imagine how to use `\number` and I am unable to find your mentioned answer. When only one space is used: `\ifcase\number#1 77zero...` then `\ifcase` joins the expansion of the `\number` with `77`. When two spaces are used then one space is printed when `#1` is not literal number.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach The `\number` primitive isn't "absolutely unnecessary" IMHO. I am using it for conversion the dimen to the number of sp units.

Comment: I think without etex you can probably do `\def\zaprelax#1\relax{}
\def\testd#1{\ifcase\expandafter\zaprelax\number#1\relax`